# Unable to call a function after fetching data in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, frontend, fetch

I'm working on a internet forum application in `reactjs + redux` and I've encoutered a problem while rendering posts of specific forums. I need to call function `loadPosts` after the application fetches data from store in `componentDidMount`.

I have tried using `this.props.fetchForums().then(loadPosts())`, however, it throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. While searching the internet I have stumbled upon many people solving this issue by having the fetch function in the component itself, but I'm trying to do a proper backend, frontend application, therefore I would like to find a different solution.

This is the fetchForums function in my actionCreator:

```
export const  fetchForums = () => dispatch => {
    fetch('http://localhost:7373/forum/all?page=0&size=2')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(forums => dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_FORUMS',
            payload: forums.content
        }));

};
```

And here is the problematic code:

```
class RenderLilPosts extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchForums();
        //Here I would like to call loadPosts
    }


    loadPosts() {
        let list = this.state.posts;
        this.props.posts.map(post => {
            list.push(post);

        });
        this.setState(
            {
                posts: list
            }
        );
    }
}

RenderLilPosts.propTypes = {
    fetchForums: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    forums: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        posts: state.forums.posts,
        forums: state.forums.storage
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchForums: () => {
        dispatch(fetchForums())
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RenderLilPosts);
```

I have omitted some parts of the code to make it more readable, hope I didn't leave out anything important. There most certainly isn't a problem with the function `fetchForums`, for whenever called using a button it does it ought to do. It's just that I don't know how to call it AFTER the data is fetched. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return` before `fetch` in your redux action. It will return a promise. Without that `undefined` is returned implicitly which obviously is not a promise. This why you get `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

```
export const fetchForums = () => dispatch => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:7373/forum/all?page=0&size=2')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(forums =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_FORUMS',
        payload: forums.content
      })
    );
};
```

Or you can remove curly braces. This will simplify the code a bit and you don't have to write `return`.

```
export const fetchForums = () => dispatch =>
  fetch('http://localhost:7373/forum/all?page=0&size=2')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(forums =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_FORUMS',
        payload: forums.content
      })
    );
```

You also have a small issue in how you use chain `fetchForums` and `loadPosts`. Should be: `this.props.fetchForums().then(() => loadPosts())`. This is useful if you need to pass params from you first call. Or `this.props.fetchForums().then(loadPosts)`

There is one more modern approach using `async` and `await` keywords but you may need additional tools like babel for that.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await this.props.fetchForums();
  loadPosts()
}
```

Note that if your second call does not depend on first call result there is no need to await or chain calls with promises.

And probably your `loadPosts` function should be a redux action as well alongside with `fetchForums`. Using state for posts is not reasonable in this case, probably you can pass posts with props and use them directly rather than saving into state.

Comment: While this would technically work it would be very poor redux since state is managed in two places.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Can you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am afraid that the problem persists. Moreover when I log type of `fetchForums` it claims to be a function. I may very well be wrong, for I am beginner in reactjs, but by my reckoning it takes some time for the function itself to be fetched, hence the undefined type.